# MySQL access denied for multiple users

Tags: mysql, sql, database, django

I'm playing around with MySQL and Django and I'm having some trouble because I'm new to this.

I'm trying to run the command:

```
    python manage.py sql login
```

to add login to my apps and I get the error:

```
    OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'classdummy'@'localhost' to database 'classydummy'")
```

I tried looking for the database 'classdummy' and user 'classdummy'@'localhost' but I didnt see them so I tried to create both

I was successful in creating a database named 'classdummy' but when I try to create a user named 'classdummy'@'localhost' I get this error:

```
    ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'classdummy'@'localhost'
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing all this correctly

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,249462,249468#msg-249468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can login to mysql as a privileged user, you can run a grant command:

```
grant all privileges on classdummy.* to 'classdummy'@'localhost' identified by 'mypassword123z';
```

Comment: I have another user called 'tommy'@'localhost'. When I run that command I get the error:

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'tommy'@'localhost' to database 'classdummy'

Not sure what to do here

Comment: login to mysql as root, do a grant

Comment: is 'mysql -r ' the correct command to login as root? or is 'mysql -u root'

I get an error when I login with the latter command 

"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' "

Comment: are u saying u cannot login as root ?  if so ask the person in charge of the box to grant access as i said for a user

Comment: -p means prompt u for the password. when you install mysql you setup the password for root (or some distro's create a different username and ask u for the password)

Comment: I actually was able to login to root and run the grants command you suggested but when I run the python manage.py command again I still got the error OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'classdummy'@'localhost' to database 'classydummy'")

Comment: post the .py somewhere like pastie and i will try it here

Comment: well it has a blank password, and my example above created an actual password

Comment: Yea I didn't include a password and the 'identified by' either when you gave me that command